# GLEW MX crashes when trying to render

Tags: opengl, glew

My GLEW MX is crashing if I move the GL function to another class ... say Point class that contains all my points and the VBO functions needed.

It basically crashes on the first GL call which to me means that the GLEWContext point is somehow null when the GL functions are getting called down in the point class.

Is there something fundamental I am missing about GLEW MX

If everything sits in main it works fine, and I can render out a simple triangle.

main.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Global_variables.h"
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fputs(description, stderr);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::thread::id thread = std::this_thread::get_id();
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    myGLEWCONTEXT = new GLEWContext();
    GLEWContext* test = glewGetContext();

    Points mPoints = Points();
    mPoints.AddPoint(Point(glm::vec3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0), glm::vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)));
    mPoints.AddPoint(Point(glm::vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec2(0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0), glm::vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)));

    mPoints.setGLMode(GL_TRIANGLES);
    mPoints.create();
}
```

Global_variables.h

```
static GLEWContext* myGLEWCONTEXT;


static GLEWContext* glewGetContext()
{
    std::thread::id thread = std::this_thread::get_id();

    return myGLEWCONTEXT;
}
```

Points.h

```
class Points 
{
public:

    //Pack Vertex
    struct PackedVertex{
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec2 uv;
        glm::vec3 normal;
        glm::vec4 color;
        bool operator<(const PackedVertex that) const{
            return memcmp((void*)this, (void*)&that, sizeof(PackedVertex))>0;
        };
    };

    Points();
    Points(int number, glm::vec3 upperleftbound, glm::vec3 lowerrightbound);
    Points(std::vector<Point> & passedinpoints);
    ~Points(void);


    void Print();
    void Render();
    bool create();

.....
```

Update: ----------------- Attempted Singlton

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

#pragma once
class glewSinglton
{


public:
    glewSinglton (const glewSinglton&) = delete;
    glewSinglton& operator=(const glewSinglton&) = delete;


    GLEWContext* myGLEWCONTEXT;

    GLEWContext* get_value()
    {
        return myGLEWCONTEXT;
    }
    void set_value(GLEWContext* v)
    {
        myGLEWCONTEXT = v;
    }
    static glewSinglton *instance()
    {
        if (!s_instance){
            s_instance = new glewSinglton;
            GLEWContext* myGLEWCONTEXT = new  GLEWContext();
        }
        return s_instance;
    }

    GLEWContext* glewGetContext()
    {
        return myGLEWCONTEXT;
    }


    static glewSinglton *s_instance;

private:
    glewSinglton();
    ~glewSinglton();

};

#endif
```

but that just gives me tons of errors in main when I put

```
#include "glewSinglton.h"

glewSinglton *mInstance = glewSinglton::instance();
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like an issue with the order static variables are initialized. You might consider using a proper singleton pattern to ensure that `myGLEWCONTEXT` is constructed by the time something tries to use it.

Comment: do you have a suggestion where to put it then?

Comment: See my answer. I believe that may straighten out part of your problem. Static variables at global scope are very hard to get working correctly.

Comment: I tried it but got...  1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl glewSinglton::glewSinglton(void)" (??0glewSinglton@@AEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class glewSinglton * __cdecl glewSinglton::instance(void)" (?instance@glewSinglton@@SAPEAV1@XZ)

Answer (score 1):

#### As explained in comments, this is probably what you need to do:

```
static GLEWContext* glewGetContext()
{
    static GLEWContext* myGLEWCONTEXT = NULL;

    std::thread::id thread = std::this_thread::get_id();

    // Initialize on first use
    if (! myGLEWCONTEXT)
        myGLEWCONTEXT = new GLEWContext();      

    return myGLEWCONTEXT;
}
```